# Nuxt - global components according to layout

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm developing Nuxt universal application, where I have two layouts one for control panel and one for frond-end UI.

And the thing I need is to register global components, but I need them to be only global for specific layout, couse I dont want to download unnecesary scripts on my front-end app in its bundle.

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration) global component's are registered on Vue prototype and will be accessible from any component within created Vue instance. That means, that as long you use single instance, all global registrations (components, filter, mixins, etc) will be shared.

So, the answer is that there is no easy way to do that, specially when Nuxt.js takes care of essential part of webpack configuration and route splitting.

Registering component's locally should be done, in order to optimize performance.

Another recommendation you might want to look at, is that even you optimize loading of components, application will still load all declared store modules, plugins, external libraries, etc. And the most important, from my experience, once automatic deployment has been setup for that application and some changes have to be deployed to control panel - whole site will have to go down for maintenance.

I would consider a good practice to separate front-end and control panel to their own apps, which keeps responsibility separated and is the only way to deliver best optimization to front-end part of application.

Control panel is usually available on a subdomain, but can be configured on the web server as a subfolder, e.g. `domain.com/control-panel`.

Comment: I considered to seperate my nuxt app, however Im using Nuxt with Adonis js for my back-end (AdoNuxt template) and I didnt figure out a way how to configure the app to use 2 instances of nuxt and still using one adonis back-end :( Wouldnt you know some soulution or guide which u can provide me?

Comment: From app architecture perspective, it makes sense to separate back-end and front-end. Since you are running AdoNuxt template, it would make sense to create a standalone application for control panel. It can be Nuxt, it can be in SPA mode or any other solution, which will communicate with main application instance API. So support and deployment has no affect on the main app.

Answer (score 0):

Two step can solve your problem:

1. make a global_component.js file into plugins directory

then add below code,

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import your_component from '../your component directory/your_component.vue'

Vue.component('your-component', your_component)
```

2. add this js file into Nuxt.config.js plugins block

> plugins: ['@/plugins/global_component.js '],

3. now you can use your component into any template like below

```html
<template>
  <section class="container">
  <your-component></your-component>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: This answer does not suggest a way to register the plugin for a specific layout. What you suggested would register the component globally and will increase bundle size for unrelated layouts which is the opposite of what is asked.